# max number of records can MariaDB support

Tags: database, mariadb

What is the max number of records (mostly numeric data, each record size not more than say 1Kb, 5/6 fields at most in a table) that can be supported?

Comment: This question would be better received on dba.stackexchange.com as it is not programming related. Generally the size available for a mysql/mariadb table is determined by limitations of the system on which the server is running, not the database server itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An InnoDB table is limited to 64TB; this might allow for 64 billion rows in one table.  There is virtually no limit on the number of tables in a database, nor the number of databases in an instance of MariaDB.

If you `PARTITION` a table, the limit is further raised, probably into the trillions of rows.  This is because each partition is essentially a separate table.

More on Limits: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits Most limits are never hit by any realistic application on current hardware.

Answer (score 10):

### Limitations on Schema

- InnoDB tables can have a maximum of 1,017 columns. This includes
  virtual generated columns.
- InnoDB tables can have a maximum of 64
  secondary indexes.
- A multicolumn index on InnoDB can use a maximum of
  16 columns. If you attempt to create a multicolumn index that uses
  more than 16 columns, MariaDB returns an Error 1070.

### Limitations on Size

- With the exception of variable-length columns (that is, VARBINARY, VARCHAR, BLOB and TEXT), rows in InnoDB have a maximum length of roughly half the page size for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB and 32KB page sizes.
- The maximum size for BLOB and TEXT columns is 4GB. This also applies to LONGBLOB and LONGTEXT.
- MariaDB imposes a row-size limit of 65,535 bytes for the combined sizes of all columns. If the table contains BLOB or TEXT columns, these only count for 9 - 12 bytes in this calculation, given that their content is stored separately.
- 32-bit operating systems have a maximum file size limit of 2GB. When working with large tables using this architecture, configure InnoDB to use smaller data files.
- The maximum size for the combined InnoDB log files is 512GB.
- With tablespaces, the minimum size is 10MB, the maximum varies depending on the InnoDB Page Size.

### Page Sizes

Using the innodb_page_size system variable, you can configure the size in bytes for InnoDB pages. Pages default to 16KB. There are certain limitations on how you use this variable.

- MariaDB instances using one page size cannot use data files or log files from an instance using a different page size.
- When using a Page Size of 4KB or 8KB, the maximum index key length is lowered proportionately.

You can read a little bit more in the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-limitations/)